# SOAP header without namespace

Tags: java, xml, spring, soap, xsd

I  want to create a SOAP header. That should contain an Element Token without namespace. If I don't give namespace I'm getting the "Header element must be namespace-qualified" error.
Below is the code I wrote.

```
QName QUsername =
          new QName("http://xxxx", "Token");
        SOAPHeaderElement soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(QUsername);
        soapHeader.addTextNode("XXX");
        QName header1 = new QName("http://xxxx", "sHeader");
        soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(header1).addChildElement(soapHeader);
```

Output I'm getting is:

```
    <soap:Header>
      <sHeader xmlns="http://xxx">
        <Token xmlns="http://xxx">
           XXXX
        </Token>
     </sHeader>
  </soap:Header>
```

Expected soap header:

```
<soap:Header>
<sHeader xmlns="http://xxxx">
<Token>XXXX</Token>
</sHeader>
</soap:Header>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It works as expected if token element is appended to `sHeader` element. The `Token` default namespace (no prefix) is inherited from `sHeader` parent.

```
QName QUsername = new QName("http://xxxx", "Token");
SOAPHeaderElement soapHeader;
try {
    MessageFactory messageFactory = MessageFactory.newInstance();
    SOAPMessage soapMessage = messageFactory.createMessage();
    SOAPPart soapPart = soapMessage.getSOAPPart();

    SOAPEnvelope envelope = soapPart.getEnvelope();
    //envelope.addNamespaceDeclaration("ex", "http://xxx");

    soapHeader = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(QUsername);
    QName header1 = new QName("http://xxxx", "sHeader");
    SOAPElement head1Child = soapMessage.getSOAPHeader().addHeaderElement(header1).addChildElement(soapHeader);
    head1Child.addTextNode("XXX");

    soapMessage.writeTo(System.out);
    System.out.println();

} catch (SOAPException | IOException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Result (formatted):

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <SOAP-ENV:Header>
    <sHeader xmlns="http://xxxx">
      <Token>XXX</Token>
    </sHeader>
  </SOAP-ENV:Header>
  <SOAP-ENV:Body/>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```